# html2pdf (html2canvas) when scale is 2 image is missing from downloaded pdf file when scale is less like 0.5 then it is rendering bu images are blur

Tags: reactjs, jspdf, html2canvas, html2pdf

html2pdf (html2canvas) when scale is 2 image is missing from downloaded pdf file when scale is less like 0.5 then it is rendering but images are blur in pdf file.

Any suggestion will be helpful to me.

Thanks